# Custom route for the Authentication component in Pages/Authentication.razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, openid-connect, blazor-webassembly

I'm setting up OIDC on a blazor WASM (standalone) app.

I have the following in `Pages/Authentication.razor`:

```
@page "/authentication/{action}"
@attribute [AllowAnonymous]

@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication

<RemoteAuthenticatorView Action="@Action" />

@code{
    [Parameter] public string? Action { get; set; }
}
```

And the following in `RedirectToLogin.razor`:

```
@inject NavigationManager Navigation

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Navigation.NavigateTo($"authentication/login?returnUrl={Uri.EscapeDataString(Navigation.Uri)}");
    }
}
```

My `Program.cs` has the following:

```cs
builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.Bind("Oidc", options.ProviderOptions);
    options.ProviderOptions.ResponseType = "code";

    //options.UserOptions.NameClaim = "preferred_username";
    //options.UserOptions.RoleClaim = "roles";
    //options.UserOptions.ScopeClaim = "scope";
});
```

**Question:** How do I change the route in `Pages/Authentication.razor` to:

```
@page "/auth/{action}"
```

Simply updating `RedirectToLogin.razor` to redirect to `auth/login` did not help. I simply see a login failed error. Seems like I'm missing something, but cannot figure out what it is!

Related documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/standalone-with-authentication-library?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#authentication-component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I simply see a login failed error.

Sounds like you failed to bind the options or you missed something in your appsettings.json

Since you bind the options with `Oidc` Section in appsettings.json

```
builder.Configuration.Bind("Oidc", options.ProviderOptions);
```

Make sure your `appsettings.json` file locates in wwwroot floder(which is quite different from other asp.net core projects)

Also,modify the login-fail/login-callback path here:

```
builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.Bind("Local", options.ProviderOptions);

    //modify the auth paths here
    options.AuthenticationPaths.LogInPath = "/auth/login";
    options.AuthenticationPaths.LogInFailedPath = "/auth/login-failed";
    options.AuthenticationPaths.LogInCallbackPath = "/auth/login-callback";
});
```

What I've tried to reproduce your issue and fix it:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: That worked. However if you could include your `appsettings.json` contents, the answer would be more complete. I was missing two things in `AddOidcAuthentication()`: (a) `AuthenticationPaths` and (b) `ProviderOptions.RedirectUri`

Comment: I did exactly what you're showing and I still genre `/authentication` after `redirect_uri` in my callback URL, hence the app is redirection to `/authentication` where I have no page/route :(